# Datetime don't match my format

Tags: python

I have a date string with this format '01/30/15' so its 'mm/dd/yy' format I think I parse a csv file, but when I try:

```
import datetime
for row in reader:
  dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(row['Date'],"mm/dd/yy")
  print dt
```

Will return :

```
ValueError: time data '01/30/15' does not match format 'mm/dd/yy'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the improper [format string](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior). You want: `%m/%d/%y`

Example:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> s = "01/30/15"
>>> dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(s, "%m/%d/%y")
>>> dt
datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 30, 0, 0)
```

Comment: This works, but there is any way that I can change so it wont display the time, for my example it will return 2015-01-30 00:00:00, I don't need that 00:00:00.

Comment: `dt.date()` will give you just the date portion.

Comment: That was it, that you so much sir :)

Answer (score 1):

```
dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(row['Date'], "%m/%d/%y")
```